# Library not loaded libssl.1.0.0.0.dylib

Tags: r, macos, rcurl

I am on MacOS 10.12.1 and trying to install RCurl (using R-devel, so need to use source packages). I haven't seen issues like these in years. Any suggestions on whether this is a Mac issue or just a standard "broken system" issue?  It looks like Apple is trying to phase out openssl in favor of TLS and crypto libraries of its own, so I thought I might ask here before trying to "fix" things I do not understand.

```
Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to either compile/build `OpenSSL` from source or install it via `MacPorts` or `Homebrew` in order to reference the file `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` which is part of it's library. You are correct to assume that Apple has changed things quite a bit; the OpenSSL provided is not a complete implementation but more a wrapper for only specific/minimal functionality.

If you are looking for simplicity I would tend to say installing OpenSSL via `MacPorts` might be my recommendation. It can easily be installed, uninstalled, and isolated, etc. from the default version.

```
$ sudo port install openssl
```

Once installed you should see the `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` in the MacPorts `lib` directory:

```
$ ls /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
```

You should then be able to rreference it as needed from within your project.

Whenever you want to go back to using the Apple default libraries you generally just comment out the export in `~/.bash_profile` that MacPorts creates:

```
# MacPorts
# export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Comment: You might be more circumspect in offering advice about R on the Mac. R processes don't necessarily share PATHs with bash processes. MacPorts installs of external libraries are a frequent source of installation difficulties in the questions posed to R-SIG-Mac. They are not supported by the maintainer of  the Mac fork of R.

Comment: @42: Good to know, although it's not clear what the scope of the issue here is. My suggestion is more in regards to obtaining access to the missing dylib rather easily, whether to temporarily copy it, reference it during a build, etc. Apparently It's not included with the default Apple implementation of OpenSSL, so the OP would need at least some means to obtain it  I'd imagine.

Comment: I'm not the one to add the missing pieces. I _think_ that the proper linkage with the static versions of R might require setting additional environment variables or modifications to the configure scripts. That's why I always try to use code from system packages from the r.att.research.com site. There are some people that happily use homebrew installed packages but I've been warned away from it.

Comment: @42: I don't use `Homebrew` because of the way it installs packages; `Macports` on the otherhand is much more isolated and doesn't step on native packages, paths, etc. And yes, I agree that static linking is ultimately the best route of course, although sometimes not an option.